# Error in h2o.deeplearning

Tags: r

I am working on h20 deep learning - autoencoders and Ihave initiated  h20 and also I have created training and testing datasets,

But  when I use h2o.deeplearning am getting the below error, any help would be helpful.

[image]

The error is

> Error in h2o.deeplearning(x = features, training_frame = train_unsupervised,  :    unused arguments (training_frame = train_unsupervised, model_id = "model_nn")"

Code Snippet:

```
  model_nn <- h2o.deeplearning(x = features,
                         training_frame = train_unsupervised,
                         model_id = "model_nn",
                         autoencoder = TRUE,
                         reproducible = TRUE,
                         ignore_const_cols = FALSE,
                         seed = 42,
                         hidden = c(10, 2, 10), 
                         epochs = 100,
                         activation = "Tanh")
```

Comment: Where's your `y` value?

Comment: y variable is response, which is nothing but "class", class is a target variable with 0 and 1.  response <- "class"

Comment: yes, but you're trying to generate a model to predict `y` so you need to include it in your model. As far as I know `y` is not implicit in `h2o` so you need to specify `y = response`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i still face same issues: Here am not using "y" because , i just want to reduce the dimensions and i will take this model output as an input and then predict the "Y" , however, i still tried using "y" directly to the model same error persists.

Comment: model_nn <- h2o.deeplearning(x = features,
                             y = response,
                             training_frame = train_unsupervised,
                             model_id = "model_nn",
                             autoencoder = TRUE,
                             reproducible = TRUE, #slow - turn off for real problems
                             ignore_const_cols = FALSE,
                             seed = 42,
                             hidden = c(10, 2, 10), 
                             epochs = 100,
                             activation = "Tanh")

Comment: Error : Error in h2o.deeplearning(x = features, y = response, training_frame = train_unsupervised,  : 
  unused arguments (training_frame = train_unsupervised, model_id = "model_nn")

Comment: Error screen shot: https://imgur.com/a/3RCpc